# How to combine this two javascript lines in just one line

Tags: javascript

am trying to figure out a way of combining the below statements

```
document.getElementById( 'div1' ).appendChild( document.createElement( 'div' ) ).id="div2";
document.getElementById( 'div2' ).appendChild( document.createTextNode( 'More about me' ) );
```

Comment: Why do you want to combine them?

Comment: IDK just curiosity because I'm learning the language, in the book I0m reading the author does this in 4 steps I just want to know if there is a way to combining them in just one single line. Sorry about my english ):

Comment: This is an excellent question because it will let you learn the recommended ways. What you're doing is mostly correct by modern standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`appendChild()` returns a reference to the node you just added, so the second `getElementById` is not necessary:

```
document.getElementById('div1').appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
.appendChild(document.createTextNode('More about me'))
.parentNode.id="div2"; // only if you need the second div to have id="div2" for some other reason.
```

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This isn't a good thing to do at all, and I will explain why in a moment.

```
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML + "<div id='div2'>More about me</div>";
```

What this does is ensure that the new `div` gets *appended* and doesn't simply replace the content of the existing `div`.

Now obviously, this is pretty ugly code.

The reason this is bad is because what we're doing is inserting what we seem to think or are led to believe are actual elements. This is false—we're inserting a string which is translated into an element later on. This is just purely inconvenient for us.

The use of DOM scripting (which is what you had before—actually creating an element and appending it) creates elements as actual HTML objects. The point is that it's just much more *pure* input (and, in most cases, executes quicker than `innerHTML`).

Using `innerHTML` is becoming much more common now, which I like to lead myself to doubt simply because I'm such a Javascript nerd and, from what I've learned (on this site, in fact), DOM scripting is much better in many, many ways.

Secondly, DOM scripting can be so much neater and easier to maintain than `innerHTML`. You can probably tell that the code I've given you above is not convenient at all. ;)